# SQL Analysis Services - query cannot be processed

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx

I am running Analysis Services, added a dimension to the mix and now I cannot browse the cube.

Browsing cube with Sql mgmt says there is an unknown error, running an MDX query in SQL Mgmt returns a value on one measure and null on other measures.

How do I go the next level to work out what it is hitting in SQL? Can I run a SQL Profile (not an MDX profile but standard SQL) and look at the call? I tried this but cannot work out what event to profile.

or How do I determine why a null is getting returned for a measure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you processed the cube?

When running MDX queries, no SQL is run at all, so you won't be able to profile that (except during processing).

Without a bit more information, I don't know if I can help... but then you would probably need to give a lot of information, or recreate the problem with a smaller set (which might be a lot of work).

Comment: I am somewhat new to SSAS. If I open a dataSourceView and browse data I see the raw data but I get the same "query could not be processed" when I view a pivotTable. Is this running a pivot table against the SQL database or the Analysis cube?

Comment: BTW - Yes I made sure I processed the cube. I was able to get one dimension of a DSV to pivot and now nothing will pivot.

Comment: First, it's worth pointing out that you have to process the cube after every major change to the structure. You're probably doing that, so... I assume you're using Visual Studio (aka. SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio) - when you open the cube, and click on the Browser tab, does it let you then browse the cube? If yes, then your cube is successfully built and deployed, and we should talk more about how the connection needs to be made; if no, then your cube hasn't been processed successfully yet, and we can talk more about that :)

Comment: Made some progress in this. After two days of not being able to even pivot data from a data source view I rebooted my machine and that worked again. I cannot get the existing database to work but I am sucessfully building a brand new cube and dimensions.

Comment: Very strange. If you get anything more concrete to go on, feel free to come back and ask for more help :)